# How to access child view controller(container view) in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a view controller which has a child view controller. Now, I want to access childVC's labels and buttons from the view controller. How can I achieve that in swift?

I have tried this:

```
var containerVc: UIViewController?
       override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: Any?){
           if segue.identifier == "tosegue" {
               //...
            }
            
           }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
var containerVc: YourContainerViewControllerClass?
       override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: Any?){
           if segue.identifier == "tosegue" {
               containerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? YourContainerViewControllerClass
            }
            
           }
```